# Django validation (Django Rest Framework) doesn't work with parallel queries

Tags: python, django, database, rest

In my DRF Film serializer I have general validate() method:

```
    def validate(self, data):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    existing_film = Film.objects.filter(title__iexact=data.get('title'),
                                        release_date=data.get('release_date'),
                                        director__iexact=data.get('director'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if existing_film:
            validation_error_message = 'Film with such parameters (title, director, release date) already exists'
            logger.warning(f'Validation error - {validation_error_message}')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(validation_error_message)

    return data
```

As you can see, it makes request to the database and compares posted film with the existing  one. Everything works well when queries are sequential. But if I try to make parallel queries (for example, from two terminal windows) validate() doesn't work properly and both identical films are being pushed to the database, which is definitely not what I expect. Should I use some sort of transactions or something? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using django development server(python manage.py runserver)  for test?. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server.  If its not the case check the isoloation level

Comment: I guess you tried in django shell, it may not work as desired if you are using django development server.

Comment: @Jisson, should I use gunicorn?

Comment: ngnix + gunicorn is a popular solution